# glRotatef() works weird in Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glrotate

I'm about to make a rotating sphere in C++ OpenGL, MFC Application.
so I declared a variable that has a spinning velocity in `demo.h` :

```
GLfloat angle;
void Init();
```

Also, I initialized that variable and implemented one normal sphere at xyz(0,0,0) in  `demo.cpp` :

```
Init();
angle += 1;
glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);
GLUquadricObj* a = gluNewQuadric();
gluSphere(a, 10, 100, 100);  //radius = 10
```

Init() is user-defined function that initiates the value of angle variable :

```
void Init() = {
    angle = 1.0;
}
```

In this situation, the sphere spins well. But if I change `angle += 1;` to `angle += angle;` ,
then the Sphere does not rotate at the same speed and finally disappears :(
I don't know what is the difference between these two. Is there a problem with applying
"+=" operator to GLfloat type variables?

Comment: Angle  += angle is multiplying by 2. Pretty quickly you'll hit the limit of what's representable as a float that way.

Comment: `angle += angle;` is similar to what `angle *= 2;` would achieve. I.e. at each execution of statement the value of `angle` is doubled. If you try this on paper you will note how fast the value of `angle` will increase. Rather sooner than later you get giant values and finally an overflow of your `GLfloat`. (It's really worth to be aware of this for every programmer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`angle += angle` doubles the rotation value every update. Depending on your update frequency, the spinning will almost immediately become completely erratic, and within a few seconds at most overflow the possible values for a float, thus becoming INFINITY, which OpenGL most likely errors out on.

Comment: Oh...you're right, I've never imagined about it. Truly Appreciate:))